# Reducing apk size for a difference game (to allow incremental downloads)

Tags: android, apk

I am working on a difference game (for android).

The apk size becomes large when I add too many levels(say 100+). I have optimized all images, etc. However the size become more than 10 Mb.

Is there any way to allow users to incrementally download 10 image files (png) at each time.

Something like only first 10 images with app install and then allowing incremental 10 images with each button click from within the app.

If I try to do it by downloading from a web server, what will I need to implement (is it async task or can I do it with something simple). In such cases, is http allowed or I need https.

Comment: `downloading from a web server` should be a correct way. `what will I need to implement` is up to you. Basically you need to download files from internet. You can use search to find out how to do that.

Comment: thanks Vlad. for my case probably Stephan answer below is more useful (no downloading). However for others who need to download, 1 solution  can be probably use download manager [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) to download files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally rather download that 10MB once and for all instead of downloading those additional images every time I play the game; it could be expensive to download all that data.  You could of course cache them, so I don't have to download them again.  And you could foreward-download an entire level of images at a time (level2.zip).  But what if I suddenly beat my own high score and proceed to a new level ... and I don't have a very good internet connection at that particular moment? If you're ruining my gaming experience, I'll delete your app and give it a bad review immediately -- and so will everyone else =)

I'd definitely recommended adding all data and not depend on the user having a fast internet connection AND is willing to pay for the download.

If you app grows too big, you should look into expansion files, but I havne't used those myself so I can't tell much more than the link:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Thanks. My add on download is also free but not having good internet connection can definitely create a problem. Plus thanks on insight about how users may perceive this. Will accept this as answer if I do not get anything better.